# Comparing multiple means against zero

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

I can use an ANOVA to test the null hypothesis:
$$
H_0:\mu_1=\mu_2=\dots=\mu_k
$$
What test can I use to test if all means are equal to zero?  That is, 
$$
\qquad H_0:\mu_1=\mu_2=\dots=\mu_k=0
$$

Comment: [Tukey's HDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tukey%27s_range_test) and multiple comparisons with [Bonferroni correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction) is all that I know of.

Comment: This is a text-book question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would perform a nested model test of the full ANOVA model to a model with no fitted parameters (i.e., not even an intercept).  This way you are performing a multiple degree of freedom test without having to make additional adjustments for multiplicity that would lose power.  Here is a quickie demo (coded in R):

```r
set.seed(2839)                        # this makes the example exactly reproducible
X = rep(c("g1", "g2", "g3"), each=5)  # here I generate indicators for 3 groups
y = rnorm(15, mean=0, sd=1)           # these are the y data, all have mean 0
data.frame(y=y, X=X)                  # this displays the generated data
#             y  X
# 1  -0.3326526 g1
# 2  -0.6323467 g1
# 3   0.2904381 g1
# 4  -0.5387858 g1
# 5  -1.5747531 g1
# 6  -1.1753466 g2
# 7  -0.6996115 g2
# 8   0.1062468 g2
# 9   0.3771112 g2
# 10  0.3553506 g2
# 11 -0.9700400 g3
# 12  0.7833358 g3
# 13 -0.2473419 g3
# 14  0.6137652 g3
# 15 -0.3200523 g3

m.full = aov(y~X)                     # here is the full model w/ 3 parameters
m.red  = aov(y~0)                     # this is the reduced model w/ 0 parameters

anova(m.red, m.full)                  # this is the nested model test
# Analysis of Variance Table
# 
# Model 1: y ~ 0
# Model 2: y ~ X
#   Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
# 1     15 7.6106                           
# 2     12 5.8372  3    1.7734 1.2152 0.3464
```

Comment: Apart from testing everything in one-go, why do you think this is a good approach?

Comment: @SmallChess, this will be more powerful than a multi-test approach that attempts to hold the familywise error rate at alpha.

Comment: +1 I think this is the most obvious, simplest approach to it.