# Omnibus 1-sample t-test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, t-test

Seems like this should be simple enough, but I haven't been able to find a solution, or even a discussion on the issue:

What is the appropriate test and model to answer the question "Is group mean A, group mean B, ***or*** group mean C different from value Y?"

It seems inappropriate to run multiple 1-sample T-tests, though I supposed I could do that and correct my p-values. It also seems like it would get rather clunky if I had a large number of groups, not to mention how clunky it would be to report those statistics.

Just to be clear, I do not want to compare group means against each other, I simply want to test the hypothesis that any one of them is different from a reference value.

Example: A hypothetical study on the effectiveness of various anti-helminth drugs that had to be ended before every individual animal was done producing worm eggs. "All study animals were euthanized on day 100, at which time fecal egg counts were not significantly different from 0 for any treatment." Note that this example is complicated by the fact that all data are 0 or a positive number (though not necessarily an integer)

Comment: This other question may be of interest https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/291967/comparing-multiple-means-against-zero

Answer (score 1):

I would just fit a linear model (ANOVA) and compare the estimated confidence intervals on each group's mean against the reference value Y.